# MIPS .asciiz first and last char are always equal

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

Here is my simple programm, it should get the string from .data convert each char into capital and finally print the string.

```
.data
    s:  .asciiz     "wassup"

.text
    la  $t0, s          # get adress of text
    add $t1, $zero, $t0     # first adress

text_loop:
    lb  $t2 , 0($t1)        # first char
    beqz    $t2, end_text       # quit loop if string ends
    sub $t2, $t2, 32
    sb  $t2, s
    add $t1, $t1, 1     # next adress
    j   text_loop       # continue loop

end_text:
    
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, s
    syscall

    li  $v0, 10     
    syscall
```

Output:
[image]

Only the first char is changed and it is always transformed into the last char.

Im 2 weeks into learning assembly so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, you don't store to the same place you load.

The line:

```
    sb  $t2, s
```

is the problem

You always store the modified character to the beginning of the string. This line should mirror the load:

```
    lb  $t2 , 0($t1)
```

and become:

```
    sb  $t2, 0($t1)
```